# add new column to data based on other data

Tags: r

I have 2 data frame and have to create a new column `varD` in `data_2` by doing some calculations based on `data_1`. The value for `varD` is to be calculated by using the formula `(varA+pi*VarB)/VarC`. So you notice I have only 2 values of `varC` in `data_2`. And for each of them, the corresponding value of `varD` would be the average i.e. calculate the 5 possible values and then take mean.

```
data_1<- data.frame(date=c("2015-01-06 00:01:00", "2015-01-06 00:01:01","2015-01-06 00:01:02", 
                           "2015-01-06 00:01:03", "2015-01-06 00:01:04"),
                    varA=c(1,5,4,8,6),
                    VarB=c(6,88,54,698,21))

data_2<-data.frame(varC=c(0.5,1.6))
```

I did `data_1$newVar<-data_1$varA+pi*data_1$VarB`. How can I add `varD` in my `data_2` with the given condition i.e. the first value for `varD` would be `{(1+pi*6)/0.5 +(5+pi*88)/0.5...}/5`?

Comment: Please clarify the last part. Thanks.

Comment: @TarJae i hope it is now clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Base `R`**

```
# get average function
myfun <- function(x, y, z) { lapply(z, function(n) mean((x + (pi * y))/n)) }
# apply your function to data
data_2$varD <- myfun(x = data_1$varA, y = data_1$VarB, z = data_2$varC )
```

**Data.table**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(data_2)
data_2[, varD := myfun(x = data_1$varA, y = data_1$VarB, z = varC )]
```

**Output:**

```
data_2
#  varC     varD
#1:  0.5 1099.104
#2:  1.6 343.4701
```

**Data:**

```
data_1<- data.frame(date=c("2015-01-06 00:01:00", "2015-01-06 00:01:01","2015-01-06 00:01:02", 
                           "2015-01-06 00:01:03", "2015-01-06 00:01:04"),
                    varA=c(1,5,4,8,6),
                    VarB=c(6,88,54,698,21))

data_2<-data.frame(varC=c(0.5,1.6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it's a bit awkward though it should work.

```
# your data
data_1<- data.frame(date=c("2015-01-06 00:01:00", "2015-01-06 00:01:01","2015-01-06 00:01:02", 
                           "2015-01-06 00:01:03", "2015-01-06 00:01:04"),
                    varA=c(1,5,4,8,6),
                    VarB=c(6,88,54,698,21))

data_2<-data.frame(varC=c(0.5,1.6))
# your calculation
data_1$newVar<-data_1$varA+pi*data_1$VarB

# safe as variable
variableC1 <- data_2[1,1]
variableC2 <- data_2[2,1]

# save your logic as variable
varD1 <- sum(data_1$newVar/variableC1)/5
varD2 <- sum(data_1$newVar/variableC2)/5

# vector for column
varD <- (c(varD1, varD2))

# add to data_2
data_2 <- cbind(varC=data_2$varC, varD)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
tmp=matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:nrow(data_2)) {
    tmp[,i]=data_1$newVar/(data_2$varC)[i]
}
varD=apply(tmp, 2, mean)
data_2[,"varD"]=varD

  varC      varD
1  0.5 1099.1043
2  1.6  343.4701
```